# Why does creating a user with e-mail and password result in 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm attempting to add e-mail and password authentication to my Firebase application:

```
this.authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(options.ref, this.onAuth.bind(this))
```

The callback is fired with both error and user set to null, as expected.

To create an account for the user, I run createUser as per the documentation:

```
 this.authClient.createUser(
     this.$el.find('.not-logged-in .email').val(),
     this.$el.find('.not-logged-in .password').val(),
     function(error, user) {
         alert('This point is never reached')
     }
)
```

Instead, I see a failed request in my console:

```
GET https://auth.firebase.com/auth/firebase/create?&firebase=PRIVATE&email=PRIVATE%40PRIVATE&password=test&callback=FirebaseAuthClient._callbacks._firebaseXDR136151713871233 502 (Bad Gateway)
```

(I left out the name of my firebase and my e-mail. They both had the expected values)

Answer (score 2):

Enable the "Email & Password" authentication provider in Firebase Forge under Auth.

Comment: Engineer at Firebase here. I'm glad that you were able to work around that problem, and I'll look into adding a more helpful error message for that error.